# c++ similar repeated inputs with different outputs from it

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include "cmath"
using namespace std;

double power(double a1, double b2)
{
    double result;
    result = pow(a1,b2);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int a1, b2, result;
    int choice = 0;
    int count = 4;
    int r1,r2,r3,r4;

    while (choice < count)
    {
        cout <<"Enter the value of coefficient." << endl
        << "Coefficient: ";
        cin >> a1;

        cout <<"Enter the value of the exponent." << endl << "Exponent: ";
        cin >> b2;
        choice++;
    }

    if (a1 == 0 && b2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "You entered 0 values. " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        r1 = power(a1,b2);
        r2 = power(a1,b2);
        r3 = power(a1,b2);
        r4 = power(a1,b2);
    
        cout << "The answers are: " << endl
        << r1 << endl << r2 << endl << r3 << endl << r4 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need to display the different output values but it only gave me the last input computation done. So how can I possibly display those first/second values? Beginner here so I'm open for some criticism.

Comment: Properly indented code should make the problem easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do but I assume that you want to ask for 8 numbers (4 times a and 4 times b). And you want to show 4 results (`r1, r2` ... ).
But when you are asking for `a` and `b` the second times, you just overwrite them with new value, when you do  `cin >> a1;`

For what you are doing I encourage you to learn about **arrays**

So you should probably do you math before overwriting them, and store the result in an **array**:

```
// declare the array of size 4

int resultArray[4];
...
...
cin >> b2;
r1 = power(a1,b2);
resultArray[choice] = r1
choice++;
}

cout << "First result :" << resultArray[0]
```

or you could store your values in the while, and do the maths after

```
// declare 2 arrays of size 4

int coefficientArray[4];
int exponentArray[4];

...

cin >> b2;
coefficientArray[choice] = a1;
exponentArray[choice] = b2;
choice++;
}

...

r1 = power(coefficientArray[0],exponentArray[0]);
r2 = power(coefficientArray[1],exponentArray[1]);
```